# Is there a quick save option in Jagged Alliance - Back in Action

Tags: jagged-alliance-bia

I've been playing the demo of Jagged Alliance: Back in Action. I'm thinking of purchasing the game, but one of the things that has been bugging me in the demo is the apparent lack of a quicksave function.

Is such a function present in the game?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no "quicksave option": You can save everytime using the "options menu", as long as you are not in combat.